# QTableView issue with selectionModel()

Tags: pyqt, qtableview, selectionmodel

I have a problem with my call to QTableView.selectionModel(). I instanciate my QTableView in another class, then when I open a new project and need to fill in my view I call a function fillGrid() in which I get the data among other things. This is also where I call the selectionModel() method.

Everything goes well the first time I call it. But if I try to call it again in the same instance of the program then it gives me the following error :

> TypeError: 'QItemSelectionModel' object is not callable

my function fillGrid looks like :

```
def fillGrid(self):

    self.infos = select.getInfosProject(self.parent.db, self.parent.currentProj)
    self.getData()
    header = ["id","hidden","state","filename","asset-shot name","task","buffer","pass","camera","version","user","date","deps","check","comment","start frame","end frame","missing frames","edit start frame","edit end frame"]
    self.model = SequenceGridModel(self.data, header, self)
    self.setModel(self.model)


    self.hideColumn(0)
    self.hideColumn(1)
    font = QtGui.QFont("Verdana", 8)
    self.setFont(font)
    vh = self.verticalHeader()
    vh.setVisible(False)
    hh = self.horizontalHeader()
    hh.setStretchLastSection(True)
    self.resizeColumnsToContents()

    self.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QTableView.SelectRows)
    self.selectionModel = self.selectionModel()
    self.connect(self.selectionModel, QtCore.SIGNAL("selectionChanged(QItemSelection, QItemSelection)"), self.getSelection)
    self.setSortingEnabled(True)


    self.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.CurrentChanged)
    self.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
    self.setItemDelegateForColumn(13,ComboBoxDelegate(self, self.checkValues))

    self.setColumnWidth(13, 64)
```

Any idea why this is happening ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've assigned your QItemSelectionModel instance to the name selectionModel, but selectionModel is a method of the QTableView class.  You need to pick a new name for your selection model.  See the [QAbstractItemView](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qabstractitemview.html) class reference.

If you want to assign that selection model to apply to your model you need to use the setSelectionModel method.